# remove tuple from list using linq

Tags: linq, removeall

Hello I have a list of a custom object (its really just a tuple), I'm trying to remove from one list where the same object is in another list. But I'm having difficulty doing so.

Here is the code:

```
public class FileNameTuple
{
    public FileNameTuple(string origFileName, string newFileName)
    {
        OrigFileName = origFileName;
        NewFileName = newFileName;
    }

    public string OrigFileName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string NewFileName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

        List<FileNameTuple> fileListing = new List<FileNameTuple>();
        List<FileNameTuple> failedFileListing = new List<FileNameTuple>();

        //doesn't work, has compliation error
        fileListing.RemoveAll(i => failedFileListing.Contains(i.OrigFileName));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Contains` compares the object itself, you want to compare a property. Use `Any`:

```
fileListing
.RemoveAll(i => failedFileListing.Any(fnt => i.OrigFileName == fnt.OrigFileName));
```

If you want to use `Contains` you need to override `Equals` (+ `GetHashCode`):

```
public class FileNameTuple
{
    //...
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if(object.ReferenceEquals(obj, this) return true;
        FileNameTuple t2 = obj as FileNameTuple;
        if(t2 == null) return false;
        return OrigFileName == t2.OrigFileName;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (OrigFileName ?? "").GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you can compare `FileNameTuple`s:

```
fileListing.RemoveAll(i => failedFileListing.Contains(i));
```

Comment: Nice that's the trick, couldn't wrap my head around that I needed to use any. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a filtered list instead of changing an existing list, you can use the [`Except` **LINQ** operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb356791.aspx).

If you can't change your class like [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) and don't want to build a custom [equality comparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms132151.aspx), you can always use my [`PredicateEqualityComparer`](http://pmlinq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Mainline/Solution/Sources/PauloMorgado.Linq/PredicateEqualityComparer.cs).

```
fileListing.Except(
    failedFileListing,
    new PredicateEqualityComparer((f1, f2) => f1.OriginalName == f2.OriginalName));
```